# Foreach during an mySql query

Tags: php, mysql

I there a way I can return several rows by using a foreach in PHP ?

Example:

I want to loop into the `Users` table and I have this list of `Users id's`.

```
$users = "1,2,3";

foreach ($users as $user) {
    SELECT * FROM Users where id = :user;
}
```

But here, I need the query the db 3 times.

Is there a way to make it in one query ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd retrieve the users first, so `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id IN (1,2,3)` then use your foreach to loop the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using where in mysql statement you can use by single query

```
SELECT * FROM Users where id in ( $users);
```

like

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id IN (1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function getUsers() {
        $sql = "SELECT
                  * FROM Users";
        //echo $sql;
        //$dbConn = new PDO('blah blah');
        $result = $dbConn->query($sql);
        //this can be output if no user exists, 
        $user= array();            
            while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                $users= array(
                //store the id's as an array here
                    'id' => $row['id'],                        
                );
                array_push($user, $users);
            }
        }
        return $user;
    }
```

//Add prepared statements here to make prevent SQL injection